# Spring Thymeleaf fails to resolve templates

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

My problem is that I fail to show a Thymeleaf template. I suspect a config error, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance :)

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
...
<properties>
        ...
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.3</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>
...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Template is in: `src/main/resources/templates/home.html`

Spring config:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/mityo
server.port=8080
...
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.mode=html5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/resources/templates/
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("buy")
public class HomeController {

    public String buy(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access: `localhost:8080/mityo/buy` and getting 404.

Another thing, can anyone explain (or give a link to docs) which servlet is used to "return" the templates html? Is it the Spring dispatcher servlet?

---

Ok so I had forgotten the `@GetMapping`, thanks @benjamin c.
Adding it however produces:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the configuration : spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/resources/templates/
By default, this location is the one used by the Thymeleaf engine.

UPDATE:
If you want to change the default location (under resources directory), you can use :
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

Answer (score 1):

Put `@RequestMapping("/")` before `buy` function:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String buy(Model model) {
    return "home";
}
```

If you have multiple functions in the class, springboot will not know which function will be used for the request. 
`SpringBoot` use `Thymeleaf` is template default. You dont need config for that.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid 404 response, add `@GetMapping` annotation to `buy` method.

```
@GetMapping
public String buy(Model model) {
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: Yes this resolved the 404, thanks :) I'm getting `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers` now however.